# "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible" / Apache on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd

I've got a brand new CentOS 6 installation, which has a symlink in the document root to my development files:

```
[root@localhost html]# ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  0 Sep 18 20:16 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Sep 18 20:16 index.php
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 24 Sep 18 20:19 refresh-app -> /home/billy/refresh-app/
```

My httpd.conf has this:

```
<Directory "/">
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</directory>
```

The target of the symbolic link has permissions which should allow apache to read anything it wants:

```
 [root@localhost billy]# ls -l
total 40 (Some entries were omitted because the list was too long
drwxr-xr-x. 7 billy billy 4096 Sep 18 20:03 refresh-app
```

I've also tried disabling SELinux by changing `/etc/selinux/conf`:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Yet no matter what I do, when someone tries to go to that link, `http://localhost/refresh-app/`, I get a 403 FORBIDDEN error page and this is written in the `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible
```

Why can't Apache access the target of the symlink?

Comment: What user is apache running as? Can you actually read that resource as that user?

Comment: As well, you're better off running selinux in permissive mode and then using sealert to parse the audit log - this lets you see why/how SELinux is denying it and often even gives you a resolution.

Comment: @draeath: I have no idea how to check for that.

Comment: @draeath: 1. This isn't a production box; I don't care if SELinux is off. 2. In any case, I am just troubleshooting at this point -- I'll probably restore it once I figure out the root cause.

Comment: Not to worry this is a common oversight, first time i did it i was stuck for days, http://serverfault.com/questions/313485/apache-configuration-for-allowing-a-web-site-that-is-a-symlink-to-a-users-directo/313516#313516 :: Its one of those errors. :D

Comment: My problem was the missing entry in the **open_basedir** That was the solution on Centos 7 and Plesk 12.0.18 http://serverfault.com/questions/628454/owncloud-refusing-to-access-data-directory/720080#720080

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Found the issue. Turns out, Apache wants access to not just the directory I'm serving, `/home/billy/refresh-app/`, but also every directory above that, namely `/home/billy/`, `/home`, and `/`. (I have no idea why... giving someone access to a subdirectory shouldn't require giving away permissions to everything above that subdirectory....)

I would guess it's looking for `.htaccess` or something, or perhaps *nix being strange about how it treats permissions for directory transversal.

Comment: It's not strange. That's how it works. You have to have +x for the entire path you're trying to access.

Comment: @bahamat: That doesn't make any sense. Why would anyone need execute privileges for files that don't get executed? (This completely discounting that one shouldn't have to give away rights to `/`... pretty much ever) Systems with ACLs usually have a separate directory transverse option. You'd think after 30 years since Unix was designed, and wide availability of ACL systems, that ACLs would be the standard. :sigh:

Comment: I believe he meant +x on directories. Try switching into the user and cd-ing to the directory w/o +x. From memory +x allows you to access but not see the directory while +r allows you to list files and +w allows you to change files in said directory

Comment: @BillyONeal: the phrase "entire path" implies directories.

Comment: yep i double checked and i remembered correctly. If you only have +x on the directories and nothing else a user cant do (or see) anything to them except browse a known path to a directory were they have permissions. So essentially you probably be ok granting o+x (x to others)

Comment: This is correct behavior in unix. You need execute privileges (+x for g or o) on parent directories that you're trying to change into sub-directories underneath them.

Comment: Then, what was the solution? Did you give permissions or updated the configuration in httpd.conf?

Comment: Can somebody translate this into a chmod command? I'm struggling with terminal. Tnx!

Comment: It seems like there should be a way to configure apache to open a file descriptor for the directory for a directory before downgrading to the www-data user. I assume that is mod_userdir works, since it allows you to view the public_html dir even if the home directory isn't executable.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem where I had the following configuration which used to work with Ubuntu 10, but stopped working with Ubuntu 14 (Apache 2.4):

```xml
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Switching to this sorted the problem (even though the web server user wasn't able to directly access the symlink)

```xml
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

From what I can tell its just the `-SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` setting and has something to do with changes in Apache 2.4 but I haven't tried researching the exact cause.

I also thought it could be down to `openbase_dir` restrictions in PHP but it wasn't that.

Answer (score 6):

This error can also be caused if you are linking to an encrypted folder.

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to check if selinux is enforced or not.
On RedHat/Fedora, execute this:

```
getenforce
```

If the response is 'Enforcing', you may want to execute

```
setenforce 0
```

and try the url again in your browser.

Note that I am not saying that disabling selinux is the best way to solve this problem, but it may help to identify the cause.

Comment: this fixed the sym link problem but is there any negative effects?

Answer (score 3):

It appears "FollowSymLinks" is the option you need in httpd.conf.  It is detailed [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/apache-and-symbolic-links-42393/).  Looks like you might need a rule in htdocs too...but it's the option you need.

Comment: See `Options All` -- `FollowSymLinks` is already specified.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution for me was to create a .htaccess file in the root of my site with this code:

```
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Comment: This in addition to `sudo chmod 755` for all the parent directories worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Create a .htaccess file with this did the trick for me (put it in a dir before the symlink).

Comment: In my case, I was making `/var/www` a symbolic link to another intermediate symbolic link. If you must use symbolic links, make it a symbolic link DIRECTLY to your destination.

Answer (score 2):

@Billey ONeil @Flion
I couldnt answer in line (low rep count)
Here was I had to do:
(**note:** alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lh')

```
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll lego
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Sep 10 21:21 lego -> /home/DATA/Documents/Chris/Synced/web/lego/
```

Now look at every directory in the source link

```
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll -d /home/DATA/Documents/Chris/Synced/web/
drwxr-xr-x 9 chris chris 4.0K Sep 12  2017 /home/DATA/Documents/Chris/Synced/web/
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll -d /home/DATA/Documents/Chris/Synced/
drwxr-xr-x 20 chris chris 4.0K Mar 27 18:52 /home/DATA/Documents/Chris/Synced/
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll -d /home/DATA/Documents/Chris/
drwxr-xr-x 36 chris chris 4.0K Jun 17 23:31 /home/DATA/Documents/Chris/
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll -d /home/DATA/Documents/
drwxr-xr-x 21 chris chris 4.0K Aug  7 18:22 /home/DATA/Documents/
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll -d /home/DATA/
drwxrwxr-- 10 root users 4.0K Sep 10 11:17 /home/DATA/
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll -d /home/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Sep 10 10:37 /home/
```

**/home/DATA** directory is the culprit.
Fix it with this:

```
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# chmod +x /home/DATA/
root@Bellach:/var/www/html# ll -d /home/DATA/
drwxrwxr-x 10 root users 4.0K Sep 10 11:17 /home/DATA/
```

The fix is immediate - no need to restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @BillyONeal this same error can occur if the the symbolic link has a different owner/group than the target folder.

For example, this folder setup will generate the `Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible` error:

```
[root@app mobile]# ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx   1 random    nobody    6      Oct 26 16:27 binary -> bundle
drwxrwxr-x+ 10 app       app       4096   Oct 26 16:26 bundle
drwxrwxr-x+  4 app       app       4096   Oct  5  2019 download
[root@app mobile]#
```

However, this folder setup works fine:

```
[root@app mobile]# ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx   1 app       app       6      Oct 26 16:27 binary -> bundle
drwxrwxr-x+ 10 app       app       4096   Oct 26 16:26 bundle
drwxrwxr-x+  4 app       app       4096   Oct  5  2019 download
[root@app mobile]#
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a shared folder for all repositories named `/home/repo`.

Then symlink from my own home like: 
`ln -s /home/repo ~/Code`
so `~/Code/www.xxxx.com/public`
points to 
`/home/repo/www.xxxx.com/public`

and also a link into apache web root 
`/var/www/html`
points to 
`/home/repo/www.xxxx.com/public`

Found it here:
https://github.com/alghanmi/ubuntu-desktop_setup/wiki/Git-Local-Repository-Setup-Guide

With some symlink+user groups acrobacy you can have multiple users/versions deployed.

Answer (score -1):

that what solve my problem after allow all permission and allow followsymlink
"
In the case of FollowSymLinks specifically it MUST be inside a Directory structure when within a .conf file. From the Apache current manual

> The FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch Options work only in
>    sections or .htaccess files.

[answer from here](https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks/244252#244252)

Answer (score -3):

You might also adjust your SELinux settings, and setenforce may not be on your path. So try this:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/setenforce 0
```

and to make this persist between reboots

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```