# Where do I set FollowSymLinks?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have just set up an Apache 2.2 server on a new Linux Mint installation. I am recreating a previous set up I had on an old Ubuntu machine.

On my previous computer, I had to enable `FollowSymLinks` in `httpd.conf`, because I store my web site HTML files in my home directory, and link to them from a symbolic link in `/var/www`.

On my new server, I can't find any `httpd.conf` anywhere, so I can't seem to set the option to follow symlinks. As a result, I'm getting a `403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server` error.

Also, in my error log, it says:

```
[Sun May 05 02:12:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/Websites
```

Has something changed in how one allows symlinks? Or am I wrong about the setting being in `httpd.conf`? In any case, how do I get my new Apache to follow symlinks?

---

**Update:** Based on an answer below, I checked in the files `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`, and they both have the `FollowSymLinks` option. Is there some other reason I might be getting the error mentioned above?

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` (which is probably a link to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`).

Comment: Thank you for responding. In those files, `FollowSymLinks` seems to be enabled. But I am getting a `Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible` error in my Apache logs (I have updated my question). Is there possibly another reason I am getting this error?

Comment: I must confess I often have to resort to trial-and-error finding solutions for Apache. First I would make sure you can access the directory the link points to, as the user for which apache is running (`www-data`?), to **test** you can also link to something like an `xyz` directory under `/tmp` with `rwxrwxrwx` permissions. If that is not it I would then try to remove the `AllowOverride None` line and make the `+FollowSymLinks` for `/var/www/`.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I poked around a bit and found the answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21339/17279). I needed to run `sudo chmod +x` on the directories in my `/home` folder that contain my HTML files. Seems to be working now.

Comment: That would indeed give the 'apache2-user' access rights to those directories.

Comment: Don't forget to give apache-user access right for those symlinks. For debian and debian derived distros, it's `sudo chown -h www-data:www-data <symink>`. For Fedora, `sudo chown -h apache:apache <symink>`. Omit any slash (/) after the symlinks otherwise the ownership change will not take effect (a noob mistake I made).