# Can't list symlinks on apache

Tags: apache-httpd, raspberry-pi

So I have an Apache server on my raspberry pi running Raspibian, where its root is at `/var/www` and I've created a symlink in www called downloads which links to `/home/pi/downloads`.

First of all, I've followed [this tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks) but I couldn't get my apache to list the symlink directory. Whenever I access localhost I get only the list of files at `/var/www` but not the symlink.

Also, I tried, just to see what happens, to change the root directory to `/home/pi/downloads` and when I access the localhost I get 403 forbidden.
I want to know why I can't see the symlink and why I'm getting the forbidden error for the `/home/pi/downloads`. Maybe Apache has to have the right to read that folder? How do I make it possible?

What I really want to do is: list my symlinks and be able to access the symlinks without getting forbidden error

Comment: Do you have [Apache's FollowSymLinks Option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have the FollowSymlinks directive in place, since that's what the tutorial covers. Then the other consideration is that the `www-data` user needs to have execute access on the directory that the symlink points to (`/home/pi/downloads`).

If `www-data` belongs to the group that owns `/home/pi/downloads`, then you can do `chmod g+x /home/pi/downloads` and Apache should immediately gain access to that directory.Otherwise, if you don't mind allowing all users to access the directory, you can do `chmod o+x /home/pi/downloads`.

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74695/where-do-i-set-followsymlinks) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381371/apache-wont-follow-symlinks-403-forbidden) for similar posts.